# Undefined javascript function in MVC view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, undefined-function

I have a simple javascript function

```
function SayTest() {
    alert("test");
}
```

I include the javascript file in my MVC 4 view

```
<script type="javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/MyScript.js"></script>
```

and call the SayTest function from within my view

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#myBtn").click(function () {
            SayTest();
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm getting an undefined function error. This is driving me nuts. If the js file was included and the function is define, why do I get an undefined function error?

Comment: Are you sure the script path is correct ?

Comment: your `MyScript.js` is not loaded.

Comment: MVC 4? If yes , you have to add the Bundle in BundleConfig.cs (RegisterBundles method)

Comment: Bring up Fiddler (or your favorite dev tools) and see if the script if being loaded (make sure you CTRL+F5 to disregard the cache).

Comment: Actually your jquery is not loaded yet just load jquer before you invoke the script

Comment: can you show the js callstack from your debug tool? from the information you supplied, it's hard to tell what's the problem, if like you said, your script is loaded and jquery is also loaded, there shouldn't be undefined error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/MyScripts/MyScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: That is not going to work. If you omit the closing tag (or use a shorthand version with "/>" at the end), the browser won't load the script.

Comment: Even fixed, that's the exact line he said he's already using.

Comment: Thank you didn't even see that I used 'javascript' instead of 'text\javascript'

Comment: @user65439: Please mark as correct answer as it may help others

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ you're right! My bad. If you edit your answer I can remove the downvote.

Comment: @rossipedia It would help other if you remove downvote also :)

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ it's my downvote (to the original answer) - sorry bro :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to include jQuery into your View page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure that's before any code that calls `$()`.

(Note: You might have to change the exact filename to match what's in your project).

Comment: Its doubtful the script engine got to "undefined function" during a click .. before hitting "$ is not defined" with no jQuery included.